# How do I add value to MongooseJS array on creation

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a `city` schema that looks something like this:

```
...
name: String,
reviews: [{
  user: String,
  text: String
}],
...
```

and I create a new `city` using:

```
var city = new City({
  name: "London",
  reviews: {user: "test user", text: "This is the review"}
});

city.save(function(err){
  //check for err
  //do stuff
});
```

but I'm getting this error:

**CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]"**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There must be another first parameter in the call to `city.save()`, and then a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object in place of array in reviews. Pass it as

```
var city = new City({
  name: "London",
  reviews: [{user: "test user", text: "This is the review"}]
});
```

Comment: It must be another issue - I'll investigate but thanks anyway